# How capture part of string included delimiter?

Tags: php, regex, string

Having a string so formed:

```
#foo1 foo2# foo3 foo4 #foo5# ##foo6# #foo7## #foo8 foo9#
```

The expected should be an array so formed:

```
array (
  [0] => #foo1 foo2#
  [1] => foo3
  [2] => foo4
  [3] => #foo5#
  [4] => ##foo6# #foo7##
  [5] => #foo8 foo9#
);
```

Or more simply splitting for space but capuring all which inside a delimiter, included it... in a array.

**NOTE:** *The string can to have repeated it.*

Comment: What do you call "the delimiter" in the 5th part: `##foo6# #foo7##`, is it `#` or `##`? What is the expected result for: `## foo6# #foo7##`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` using this alternation regex:

```
/(#+).*?\1|\S+/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HhEYEn/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(#+)` - Match 1 or more `#` in captured group #1
- `.*?` - Match 0 or more of any characters (non-greedy)
- `\1` - Back-reference to captured group #1 to make sure we have same `#`s on RHS
- `|` - OR
- `\S+` - one or more non-white-space characters

**Code:**

```
$str = '#foo1 foo2# foo3 foo4 #foo5# ##foo6# #foo7## #foo8 foo9#';

preg_match_all('/(#+).*?\1|\S+/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => #foo1 foo2#
    [1] => foo3
    [2] => foo4
    [3] => #foo5#
    [4] => ##foo6# #foo7##
    [5] => #foo8 foo9#
)
```

Comment: I think the current `(#+).*?\1|\S+` regex will not match the [`foo4#foo5#`](https://regex101.com/r/HhEYEn/2) correctly.

Comment: OP's example shows strings wrapped in `#`s or whitespace. But we can  change above regex to [`(#+).*?\1|[^\s#]+`](https://regex101.com/r/HhEYEn/3) if whitespace is not a delimiter.